# Match 4 columns and replace 1 in 2 files

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have 2 files, and column 1 of file 1 must replace with column 2 of file 2, after column 2,3,4-5 or 5-4 (cross-match) of file 1 match with the column 1,4,5-6 or 6-5 of file 2.

file 1

```
SNP     Chr     Pos     EA      NEA     EAF     Beta    SE      Pvalue  Neff
1:79137     1       79137       A       T       0.25    -0.026  0.0073  4.0e-04 231420
1:79033      1       79033        A       G       0.0047  -0.038  0.056   4.9e-01 225429
1:118630     1       118630       C       T       0.99    -0.033  0.055   5.5e-01 226311
1:533179     1       533179       A       G       1       -0.098  0.19    6.1e-01 185906
```

file 2

```
1       1:79033_A_G     0       79033   A       G
1       1:79137_A_T     0       79137   T       A
1       1:118630_C_T    0       118630  T       C
1       1:533179_A_G    0       533179  G       A
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
SNP     Chr     Pos     EA      NEA     EAF     Beta    SE      Pvalue  Neff
    1:79137_A_T     1       79137       A       T       0.25    -0.026  0.0073  4.0e-04 231420
    1:79033_A_G      1       79033        A       G       0.0047  -0.038  0.056   4.9e-01 225429
    1:118630_C_T     1       118630       C       T       0.99    -0.033  0.055   5.5e-01 226311
    1:533179_A_G     1       533179       A       G       1       -0.098  0.19    6.1e-01 185906
```

The files don't have the exact number of rows and the files are not tab-delimited. I tried the below code but it doesn't work, Can you correct my code?

```
awk 'NR==FNR{chr[$1]=$1;snp[$2]=$2;pos[$4]=$4;a1[$5]=$5;a2[$6]=$6;next} ($1 in chr)&&($4 in pos)&& ((($5 in a1) && ($6 in a2)) || (($6 in a1) && ($5 in a2))) {$2==snp[$2]}' file 2 file1
```

Edit 1:

the perl code below makes some mistakes and produces duplicate lines in around 20 000 lines, one example is,

file 1

```
SNP     Chr     Pos     EA      NEA     EAF     Beta    SE      Pvalue  Neff
7:10100610      7       10100610        A       G       0.0002  0.13    0.58    8.2e-01 120658
7:10100610      7       10100610        C       G       0.0013  0.1     0.13    4.4e-01 139170
10:1006107      10      1006107 C       G       1       -0.11   0.42    7.9e-01 152016
```

file 2

```
7       7:10100610_G_A  0       10100610        A       G
7       7:10100610_G_C  0       10100610        C       G
10      10:1006107_C_G  0       1006107 G       C
```

Expected Output of these lines:

```
7:10100610_G_A      7       10100610        A       G       0.0002  0.13    0.58    8.2e-01 120658
7:10100610_G_C      7       10100610        C       G       0.0013  0.1     0.13    4.4e-01 139170
10:1006107_C_G      10      1006107 C       G       1       -0.11   0.42    7.9e-01 152016
```

But the output the perl code gives

```
7:10100610_G_A  7       10100610        A       G       0.0002  0.13    0.58    8.2e-01 120658
10:1006107_C_G  7       10100610        C       G       0.0013  0.1     0.13    4.4e-01 139170
10:1006107_C_G  10      1006107 C       G       1       -0.11   0.42    7.9e-01 152016
```

Comment: Do you need to preserve the exact amount of whitespace between columns, or is it OK to collapse each gap down to a single space (which `awk` tends to do)?

Comment: It is OK to collapse each gap down.

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `join` command will do the work of joining up matching lines from multiple files.  But it has some requirements on its input files, so you'll need to make some temporary files along the way, with a few extra fields.

```
awk '{printf $2" "$3" "$4" "$5"%"$1"%"; $1="";print $0 "%" NR }' < file1 | sort > 1.tmp
awk '{print $1" "$4" "$5" "$6"%"$2} $5 != $6 {print $1" "$4" "$6" "$5"%"$2}' < file2 | sort > 2.tmp

join -a 1 -t % -o 1.4 2.2 1.2 1.3  1.tmp 2.tmp | sort -t % -n | awk -F %  '!$2{$2=$3}{print $2" "$4}'
```

## Step by step

Preprocessing the first file:

```
awk '{printf $2" "$3" "$4" "$5"%"$1"%"; $1="";print $0 "%" NR }''
```

Example output:

```
1 118630 C T%1:118630% 1 118630 C T 0.99 -0.033 0.055 5.5e-01 226311%4
```

Those 4 fields, separated by `%`, are:

- the "key" that has to be matched (input fields 2-5)
- the original first column (needed in case there's no match)
- the remainder of the original line
- the original line number (so we can restore the file order after `sort`)

This output is piped through `sort` and into a temporary file, because `join` requires its inputs to have been sorted.

For the second file:

```
awk '{print $1" "$4" "$5" "$6"%"$2} $5 != $6 {print $1" "$4" "$6" "$5"%"$2}'
```

Example output:

```
1 118630 C T%1:118630_C_T
1 118630 T C%1:118630_C_T
```

As you specified that fields 5 and 6 should match either way round, a second line is printed with them swapped (provided that they aren't identical).  The `%`-separated fields here are

- the "key" to be matched
- column 2

Again, the output is piped through `sort` and into another temporary file.

Then comes the main "join" step:

```
join -a 1 -t % -o 1.4 2.2 1.2 1.3  1.tmp 2.tmp
```

The `-a 1` instructs `join` to keep lines from the first set when there's no match in the second.  `-t %` sets the separator to `%` (rather than whitespace).  The `-o` argument produces the following four fields of output:

- file 1, column 4: the line number
- file 2, column 2: replacement from `file2` (when there's no match, this will be empty)
- file 1, column 2: the original column1 from `file1`
- file 1, column 3: the rest of the line from `file1`

Example output line:

```
4%1:118630_C_T%1:118630% 1 118630 C T 0.99 -0.033 0.055 5.5e-01 226311
```

Then `sort` can restore the original file order (sort numerically, field separator `%`)

```
sort -t % -n
```

The final `awk` checks whether the "replacement" field is empty (because no match was found) and if so, uses the original column1 instead.  It also discards the line number and all those `%`s.

```
awk -F % '!$2{$2=$3}{print $2" "$4}'
```

Final output line:

```
1:118630_C_T  1 118630 C T 0.99 -0.033 0.055 5.5e-01 226311
```

Comment: Hey! This code works but it also removes the lines that don't match, is there a way you edit the code so that the unmatching lines are kept unchanged? Thank you!

Comment: @cookiemonster That's possible with `join`'s `-a` option -- although it involves changing the temporary files to include the original, instead of always discarding it.  Edited.  This also means the header line goes through unchanged, so I could remove the `sed q` that copied it.

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

I'd do this in Perl because it has a `sort` function that lets us treat `A T` and `T A` as the same thing easily. For example (showing the output on all of your example files combined):

```
$ perl -lane 'if(!$k){$name{join("","chr".$F[0],$F[3],sort($F[4],$F[5]))}=$F[1]; }else{$var=join("", "chr".$F[1],$F[2],sort($F[3],$F[4])); $F[0]=$name{$var} if $name{$var};print join "\t", @F; } $k++ if eof' file2 file1
SNP Chr Pos EA  NEA EAF Beta    SE  Pvalue  Neff
7:10100610_G_A  7   10100610    A   G   0.0002  0.13    0.58    8.2e-01 120658
7:10100610_G_C  7   10100610    C   G   0.0013  0.1 0.13    4.4e-01 139170
10:1006107_C_G  10  1006107 C   G   1   -0.11   0.42    7.9e-01 152016
1:79137_A_T 1   79137   A   T   0.25    -0.026  0.0073  4.0e-04 231420
1:79033_A_G 1   79033   A   G   0.0047  -0.038  0.056   4.9e-01 225429
1:118630_C_T    1   118630  C   T   0.99    -0.033  0.055   5.5e-01 226311
1:533179_A_G    1   533179  A   G   1   -0.098  0.19    6.1e-01 185906
```

Or, slightly more legibly:

```
$ perl -lane 'if(!$k){
                $name{join("","chr".$F[0],$F[3],sort($F[4],$F[5]))}=$F[1]; 
              }
              else{
                $var=join("", "chr".$F[1],$F[2],sort($F[3],$F[4])); 
                $F[0]=$name{$var} if $name{$var};
                print join "\t", @F; 
             } 
            $k++ if eof' file2 file1
SNP Chr Pos EA  NEA EAF Beta    SE  Pvalue  Neff
7:10100610_G_A  7   10100610    A   G   0.0002  0.13    0.58    8.2e-01 120658
7:10100610_G_C  7   10100610    C   G   0.0013  0.1 0.13    4.4e-01 139170
10:1006107_C_G  10  1006107 C   G   1   -0.11   0.42    7.9e-01 152016
1:79137_A_T 1   79137   A   T   0.25    -0.026  0.0073  4.0e-04 231420
1:79033_A_G 1   79033   A   G   0.0047  -0.038  0.056   4.9e-01 225429
```

#### Explanation

- `perl -lane`: the `-a` makes perl act like awk, automatically splitting its input into the array `@F` on whitespace. Since perl arrays start at `0`, `$F[0]` will be the first field, `$F[1]` will be the second etc. Field N is `$F[N-1]`. The `-n` makes perl read its arguments as text files and apply the script given by `-e` to each line of them. The `-l` just removes trailing newlines from each input line and adds a newline to each `print` call.
- `$k++ if eof` : this increments the the variable `$k` by 1 if we've reached the end of a file (`eof`). We can then use `if(!$k)` (if $k is not defined) as an equivalent to `NR==FNR` in awk.
- if(!$k){$name{join("","chr".$F[0],$F[3],sort($F[4],$F[5]))}=$F[1];}`: if this is the first file,`file2`, join fields 1, 4, and the sorted fields 5 and 6, into a string and use that string as the key in the hash (associative array)`name`. Then, save the variant's name from file2 as the value associated with that key. The sorting lets us treat`A T`and`T A`as equivalent. I use`"chr".$F[0]`to deal with cases like`1 123`and`11 23`, where the concatenation of the chromosome and position give the same number even though the chromosome is actually different.
- `else{` : if we're now reading the second file, `file1`.
- `$var=join("", $F[1],$F[2],sort($F[3],$F[4]));` : build the key. This time using fields 2, 3, and sorting 4 and 5.
- `$F[0]=$name{$var} if $name{$var};` : set the 1st field to the value stored in the `name` hash, if there is a value for this key. The `if` is needed to make sure we don't change the header or any other variants that might be present in `file1` but not in `file2`.
- `print join "\t", @F;` : print the fields, including the change just made above.

Comment: But It replaced the chr column with the names and chr values are lost, which I would not want. I need the SNP column to be replaced

Comment: I figured out how to replace the SNP column, but now ı have another problem. In file 2, i have lines like 1:100010526_C_A and  14:100010526_C_A.  The code you provided replaces 1:100010526 in file 1 with  14:100010526_C_A,  instead of  1:100010526_C_A. This happens on many lines, so I think this code needs some adjustment :/

Comment: @cookiemonster sorry! I had a silly bug (I even mentioned it in the explanation but didn't realize it!), I was changing the 2nd field instead of the 1st one. See updated answer.

Comment: I see you changed which columns to replace, but as I said, It still does not take the chr column to account while replacing the columns, producing many duplicate lines.

Comment: It cannot make the Pos column matching correctly. Why not?

Comment: One example of the duplicate lines it produces

10:1006107_C_G       7       10100610        C       G  
10:1006107_C_G        10      1006107 C       G

Comment: @cookiemonster ah, I see what you mean now. Next time, please make sure your example file is actually representative of your input data so this sort of problem can be avoided. The updated answer should be correct now.

Comment: It still does not work, I really have no idea why.
'10:1006107_C_G  7       10100610        C       G'
'10:1006107_C_G  10      1006107 C       G '

One of the duplicate line it produces i guess problem occurs where Pos and Chr combination is similar.

Comment: @cookiemonster please edit your question and give a file that has this problem. I can't debug without having the actual problem data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97765/discussion-between-cookiemonster-and-terdon).